# Using exit() and header() to redirect as a one-liner

Tags: php

My question is about writing the following as a one-liner:

```
header('Location: www.somesite.com');
exit(0);
```

PHP documentation says you can also write `exit('some string');` and it will output that string. I figured the `header()` function just creates some raw HTTP header and this should be a string of text right? So the equivalent of the above two lines could be:

```
exit(header('Location: www.somesite.com'));
```

I tested it a bit and it works (i.e exits properly and redirects.. havn't seen any shennenigans going on yet).

However,I cannot find anything about this on google and I am not 100% sure the `header()` creates an actual string that the `exit()` function expects.

**So is it a cool trick or wrong use of PHP functions and if wrong, why?**

Comment: `header()` doesn't return a value.

Comment: You could just as easily just do `header(...);exit();`. But readability is an important factor too.

Comment: Readability is wayyyyyyyyy more important than your cutesy one-liner. The longer you write code the more you realize that "clever" is the enemy. Be as explicit as is reasonable at *ALL* times in your code.

Comment: *"Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."* (c) Brian Kernighan

Comment: I suspect, and I may be wrong, but I suspect that you didn't find anything on Google because this is trivial -- no one talks about it because it isn't very important. Try to find an article about whether you can use `print` as a conditional in `if`, for example (hint: you can). As you discover the answer, you'll also discover that it hardly merits a blog post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

header() does not return anything to the exit() function - it sends out raw http headers and has a return type of void. The exit() function does not require a mandatory parameter, so yeah I think what you do would work :)

Comment: So it means exit() doesn't get called ? isn't that  bad prcatise ?

Comment: Ah yes, I read 'used to send a raw HTTP header' and thought it would return something. But ye `void` is ofcourse not returning anything. Thanks

Comment: @AyeshK `redirect` doesn't guarantee that the script stops at that moment. It simply sends a raw http header. So the `exit` would still get called.

Answer (score 1):

Even through you could do that, but two line code is more readable and clean.

```
header('Location: www.somesite.com');
exit(0);
```

If you want one line, you could make a function.

```
function redirect($url) {
    header("Location: $url");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Yes calling a function to make it a one-liner in other places is probably the best idea for readability. But the one-liner thing with the exit/header combo really got me when I couldn't find anything about it on google. So I just had to know